# How can I solve the error of "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"?

Tags: pdf, java, jpdfbookmarks

I was wondering how to solve the following error:

```
$ java -Xms64m -Xmx512m -splash:  -jar "/home/t/programs/jpdfbookmarks-2.5.2/jpdfbookmarks.jar" ./in.pdf -apply bmks.jpdf  -o out.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.clean(MappedRandomAccessFile.java:203)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFile.close(MappedRandomAccessFile.java:178)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.close(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:295)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.close(PRTokeniser.java:128)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:526)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:165)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:154)
at it.flavianopetrocchi.jpdfbookmarks.itextbookmarksconverter.iTextBookmarksConverter.save(iTextBookmarksConverter.java:397)
at it.flavianopetrocchi.jpdfbookmarks.Applier.save(Unknown Source)
at it.flavianopetrocchi.jpdfbookmarks.JPdfBookmarks.applySave(Unknown Source)
at it.flavianopetrocchi.jpdfbookmarks.JPdfBookmarks.apply(Unknown Source)
at it.flavianopetrocchi.jpdfbookmarks.JPdfBookmarks.start(Unknown Source)
at it.flavianopetrocchi.jpdfbookmarks.JPdfBookmarks.main(Unknown Source)
```

Hera are the files' information:

```
$ ls -lh
total 60M
-rw-r--r-- 1 t users  14K Oct 10 20:14  bmks.jpdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 t users  53M Oct 10 20:30  in.pdf
...
```

and JVM information

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3+7-nixos)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3+7-nixos, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Well, it complains about heap space and `java -Xms64m -Xmx512m ` is setting up the heap, so have you tried making the `512` bigger? Say to 1024 or 2048?

Comment: See https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control/